# Call function from customButton fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I have added a custom button to my `fullcalendar`:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.calendarOptions = {
  customButtons: {
    custom1: {
      text: 'Add event',
      click() {
        this.openModal();
     }
    }
  },
  height: 600,
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: false,
  locale: 'lt',
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today, custom1,custom2',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },
  events: ''
};}
```

and on the button click I want to call function:

```
    openModal() {
console.log('opened');
// '<app-add-event></app-add-event>';}
```

however, I get error `zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: this.openModal is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.click (events-calendar.component.ts:20)`

I do not know what's wrong. How do you call custom function?

I also tried:

```
 this.calendarOptions = {
  customButtons: {
    custom1: {
      text: 'Pridėti įvykį',
      click:
        this.openModal
    }
  }, ...   };
```

In this case `console.log();` work but I still get the following error after that. What is wrong here?

Should I declare this function somewhere here?

```
<ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)" (eventDrop)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
          (eventResize)="updateEvent($event.detail)" (clickButton)="clickButton($event.detail)"></ng-fullcalendar>
```

Comment: You might want to try 
```
this.calendarOptions = {
  customButtons: {
    custom1: {
      text: 'Pridėti įvykį',
      click:
        this.openModal()
    }
  }, ...   };
```

While including the parantheses in `this.openModal`

Answer (score 3):

From the [fullcalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons):

```
  customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
      text: 'custom!',
      click: function() {
        alert('clicked the custom button!');
      }
    }
  }
```

You can see that there is an issue in your custom button declaration for the `click()` property.

I'm suprised you still have the error referencing `this.openModal`. 
Since you stated you tried `click: this.openModal`, I would suggest you to give a shot to `click : () => console.log('clicked')`. 
If it works, the problem might come from usage of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fat arrow function, like so:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
  customButtons: {
    custom1: {
      text: 'Add event',
      click: () => this.openModal()
    }
  }
}
```